# How Can Someone With Minimum Programming Experience Publish an App of an Existing Program not found in the Software Centre?

Tags: software-center, application-development, packaging

There's a free mathematics software that I would like to see in Ubuntu Software Centre, called, 'Sage.' I have minimal experience in programming, so I'm basically here asking if someone could either tell me how to accomplish this without said instructions being completely over my head or if someone could do it for me. For further information here's the sage homepage: http://sagemath.org/ and the .tar.lzma file for its installation is ~500MB and it takes around 2.2 GB on the HDD when installed, I found at least on 32 bit i386 Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like someone has already packaged it, and is offering it through a personal package archive: [https://launchpad.net/~aims/+archive/sagemath](https://launchpad.net/%7Eaims/+archive/sagemath)

To install it, open Terminal and give the following commands:

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:aims/sagemath
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install sagemath-upstream-binary

See also: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sage-devel/CndzZDSLsXM

---

Update: It looks like since Bionic (18.04), sagemath seems to be available directly from the standard Ubuntu repositories:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sagemath

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to do it yourself, you can follow the process outlined on the "New Packages" wiki page:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages

Note that there may be licensing or other non-technical reasons that a particular program isn't already packaged and included in the repositories.

Comment: further, there's a whole wiki page about sage: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SAGE

Comment: Thanks mate! (I'm Aussy, just to make this sound less weird)

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to install the latest release of sage, it's quite simple. Open terminal (ctrl+T) and paste the following:

**For i686 Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS:**

```
wget http://boxen.math.washington.edu/home/sagemath/sage-mirror/linux/32bit/sage-?-linux-32bit-ubuntu_12.04.1_lts-i686-Linux.tar.lzma
```

Where ? is the latest stable release number which as of the present is 5.3.

**For x86-64 bit Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS:**

```
wget http://boxen.math.washington.edu/home/sagemath/sage-mirror/linux/64bit/sage-?-linux-64bit-ubuntu_12.04.1_lts-x86_64-Linux.tar.lzma
```

After the download is complete the following commands are universal:

```
tar --lzma -xvf Sage-Tarball-Name.tar.lzma
sudo rm Sage-Tarball-Name.tar.lzma
cd /home/username/Sage-Tarball-Name
ln -s /home/username/Sage-Tarball-Name/sage /usr/local/bin/sage
```

That's it! Sage's installation is to all the world complete. To open just open a terminal and type, 'sage' and it should open the command-line interface.

If you want a launcher for your desktop copy these commands into terminal:

```
ln -s /home/username/Sage-Tarball-Name/sage /home/username/Desktop/Launcher-Name
```